# Passing values between dialog boxes in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

When using MFC, if i have a main dialog box, then I another dialog box is called from the main, what message is sent to the main dialogue box to let it know it has focus, is it WM_SETFOCUS()? If so, what paramaters are needed? The problem I have is, a value is selected in the child dialog and I want it copied to an edit control in the main dialog box once it (the child dialog) closes. Right now, I have it so the second dialog box copies its value to a global variable, but once the second dialog box closes, I wanted to the main dialog box to grab the global variable and display in the edit control.

Comment: Is your secondary dialog a modal dialog or a modeless dialog?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a member variable in the child dialog box, like

```
CChildDialogBox dlg;
if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) // child dialog saves the value in a CString member variable m_str
{   GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(dlg.m_str);
}
```

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwz5tb1x.aspx) describes how you can set up member variables connected to controls in a dialog box.

Comment: I've tried this, but even though the variable is updated with the new values, I still can't get it to display in the edit control. Here's the situation, my main dialog box has an option to load preloaded numbers instead of manually entering them. So when the user selects one of the numbers from a popup dialog window, I want it to show up in the main dialog window, when the list is closed. Does the main dialog receive a message, that it has focus?

Answer (score 0):

I realized my problem, really a beginner's mistake, I though after a DoModal call a function would immediately exit. I didn't know I could perform additional code(assigning the edit control variable a new value and then SetWindowText) after the call, before the function ended.